# Finding the strings in a TreeSet that start with a given prefix

Tags: java, treeset

I'm trying to find the strings in a `TreeSet<String>` that start with a given prefix. I found a previous question asking for the same thing — [Searching for a record in a TreeSet on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228350/searching-for-a-record-in-a-treeset-on-the-fly) — but the answer given there doesn't work for me, because it assumes that the strings don't include `Character.MAX_VALUE`, and mine can.

(The answer there is to use `treeSet.subSet(prefix, prefix + Character.MAX_VALUE)`, which gives all strings between `prefix` (inclusive) and `prefix + Character.MAX_VALUE` (exclusive), which comes out to all strings that start with `prefix` *except* those that start with `prefix + Character.MAX_VALUE`. But in my case I need to find *all* strings that start with `prefix`, *including* those that start with `prefix + Character.MAX_VALUE`.)

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the type of cityNames? Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I suggest re-examining your requirements. `Character.MAX_VALUE` is U+FFFF, which is not a valid Unicode character and never will be; so I can't think of a good reason why you would need to support it.

But if there's a good reason for that requirement, then — you need to "increment" your prefix to compute the least string that's greater than all strings starting with your prefix. For example, given `"city"`, you need `"citz"`. You can do that as follows:

```
/**
 * @param prefix
 * @return The least string that's greater than all strings starting with
 *         prefix, if one exists. Otherwise, returns Optional.empty().
 *         (Specifically, returns Optional.empty() if the prefix is the
 *         empty string, or is just a sequence of Character.MAX_VALUE-s.)
 */
private static Optional<String> incrementPrefix(final String prefix) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(prefix);

    // remove any trailing occurrences of Character.MAX_VALUE:
    while (sb.length() > 0 && sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == Character.MAX_VALUE) {
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    }

    // if the prefix is empty, then there's no upper bound:
    if (sb.length() == 0) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    // otherwise, increment the last character and return the result:
    sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, (char) (sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) + 1));
    return Optional.of(sb.toString());
}
```

To use it, you need to use `subSet` when the above method returns a string, and `tailSet` when it returns nothing:

```
/**
 * @param allElements - a SortedSet of strings. This set must use the
 *                      natural string ordering; otherwise this method
 *                      may not behave as intended.
 * @param prefix
 * @return The subset of allElements containing the strings that start
 *         with prefix.
 */
private static SortedSet<String> getElementsWithPrefix(
        final SortedSet<String> allElements, final String prefix) {

    final Optional<String> endpoint = incrementPrefix(prefix);

    if (endpoint.isPresent()) {
        return allElements.subSet(prefix, endpoint.get());
    } else {
        return allElements.tailSet(prefix);
    }
}
```

See it in action at: http://ideone.com/YvO4b3.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you my savior

Comment: Reason is professor requirements, may be for deeper understending of tree structure, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for a shorter version of ruakh's answer:

First element is actually set.ceiling(prefix),and last - you have to increment the prefix and use set.floor(next_prefix)

```
public NavigableSet<String> subSetWithPrefix(NavigableSet<String> set, String prefix) {
    String first = set.ceiling(prefix);
    char[] chars = prefix.toCharArray();
    if(chars.length>0)
        chars[chars.length-1] = (char) (chars[chars.length-1]+1);
    String last = set.floor(new String(chars));
    if(first==null || last==null || last.compareTo(first)<0)
        return new TreeSet<>();
    return set.subSet(first, true, last, true);
}
```

Comment: This misbehaves when `prefix` is empty or ends with `Character.MAX_VALUE`; and it's needlessly complicated for the cases that it does support. (And why would anyone be "looking for a shorter version of ruakh's answer"?)